# How to detect if android device is lower or higher end (Like moto e, moto g or nexus 5x)

Tags: android, performance, android-memory

I want to detect if android device hardware is capable enough to run app's certain functions smoothly.

My implementation so far,

checking

- Memory percentage available.
- CPU Usage.
- Max CPU Freq MHz.

Results :
* Nexus 5 : 
CPU Usage => 9.243698
Memory Percent Avail => 33.6358 %
Max CPU Freq MHz => 1440

- Nexus 5x : 
  CPU Usage => 12.2XXX
  Memory Percent Avail => 47.XXXXX %
- Moto G2 : 
  CPU Usage => 44.XXXX
  Memory Percent Avail => 10.XXXX %

My flow in Nexus 5x is working awesome but not in Nexus 5, moto g and moto e.

```
//onCreate

    Log.d(LOGTAG, "Cpu Info" + Utility.getCpuInfo());

    Log.d(LOGTAG, "Memory Info" + Utility.getMemoryInfo());

    Log.d(LOGTAG, "Memory Percent Avail" + Utility.getMemoryPercentAvail(getContext()));

    Log.d(LOGTAG, "CPU Usage" + Utility.readCPUUsage());

    Log.d(LOGTAG, "Max CPU Freq MHz" + Utility.getMaxCPUFreqMHz());

// Get Memory Percent Avail

 public static double getMemoryPercentAvail(Context context) {

    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    double availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;

    //Percentage can be calculated for API 16+
    double memoryAvail = (double) mi.availMem / (double) mi.totalMem;
    return memoryAvail * 100;
}

// Read CPU Usage

public static float readCPUUsage() {

    try {
        RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");
        String load = reader.readLine();

        String[] toks = load.split(" +");  // Split on one or more spaces

        long idle1 = Long.parseLong(toks[4]);
        long cpu1 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[5])
                + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(360);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        reader.seek(0);
        load = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        toks = load.split(" +");

        long idle2 = Long.parseLong(toks[4]);
        long cpu2 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[5])
                + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        return ((float)(cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1))) * 100;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}

// Get Max CPU Freq In MHz

public static int getMaxCPUFreqMHz() {

    int maxFreq = -1;
    try {

        RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile( "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state", "r" );

        boolean done = false;
        while ( ! done ) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if ( null == line ) {
                done = true;
                break;
            }
            String[] splits = line.split( "\\s+" );
            assert ( splits.length == 2 );
            int timeInState = Integer.parseInt( splits[1] );
            if ( timeInState > 0 ) {
                int freq = Integer.parseInt( splits[0] ) / 1000;
                if ( freq > maxFreq ) {
                    maxFreq = freq;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch ( IOException ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return maxFreq;
}
```

Comment: doesn't fetching the model name of the phone do the job? Based on that you decide if the model is high end or not

Comment: Just device name can't help, as there are lots of low budget devices. Like recently Reliance Jio.

Comment: Well! make a database for the model name and whether they are low or high end. Based on that, you could execute the code. That's the way I know of, there would be folks who knows better and would help you out.

Comment: @7geeky - I did this a few years ago on a voip app allowing us to change audio settings depending on the device, while it was ok for custom settings for problematic (reported) devices, its just not possible to keep up with all the android models out there.

Comment: Just let the user decide. Some may want all functions even if it will work slow. Or actively integrate a benchmark. Passively you will not get valid results.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend taking a look at the way Telegram messenger classifies devices by performance in 3 categories [here](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/220f6b4d73793c57ba6f9023b8d38d171f342a7e/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/SharedConfig.java#L1558). They are using a combination of number of CPUs, max CPU frequency, memory class, and android version to decide about devices. Since Telegram is installed on more than 1 billion devices, I assume their approach should be reliable.

Also there is [Jetpack's performance library](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/using-performance-class-to-optimize.html) which only works on devices running android 11 and above, and is intended mostly for media use cases.

You may also take some inspiration from [Facebook's year class library](https://github.com/facebookarchive/device-year-class), but keep in mind that their data is out of date, and it hasn't been updated for a long time.